# Rewrite friendly URL, differents patterns

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the folowing rewrite rule

```
<filesMatch  "^(member)$">
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  /member-profile.php?ID=$2 [L]
</filesMatch>

<filesMatch  "^(community-events)$">
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  /community-events.php?ID=$3 [L]
</filesMatch>
```

Which is, obviously rewriting this

```
mydomain.com/comunity-events/category/id/name
```

to this

```
mydomain.com/comunity-events.php?myvariables
```

Now, I want a new redirect which doesn't have a starting "folder", like this

```
mydomain.com/business-category/business-name
```

to

```
mydomain.com/business-profile.php?variables
```

Is that even possible, given the current configuration, without making a redirect for each category name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need `filesMatch` directives as you can match starting part in `RewriteRule` itself.

You can replace your .htaccess with these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# handle /member/...
RewriteRule ^/?(member)/(.*)/(.*)$ /member-profile.php?ID=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# handle /community-events/...
RewriteRule ^/?(community-events)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /community-events.php?ID=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

# handle /business-category/business-name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)$ business-profile.php?name=$2 [L,QSA]
```